# Result not getting when transfer xml to xsl using java

Tags: java, xslt-1.0

Could any one help me?

**XMLFile:**

```
<dataXML>
    <Items>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>1</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>001</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test1</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>2</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>001</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test2</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>3</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test3</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>4</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test4</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>5</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>002</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test5</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
        <itemLine>
            <lineNo>6</lineNo>
            <lineRefNo>003</lineRefNo>
            <lineDes>test6</lineDes>
        </itemLine>
    </Items>
</dataXML>
```

Input xml is sorted on lineRefNo Node

**XSL File:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="kItemsByRef" match="itemLine" use="lineRefNo"/>
<xsl:template match="itemLine[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kItemsByRef', lineRefNo)[1])]">
Header<xsl:for-each select="key('kItemsByRef', lineRefNo)">
LineNo: <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ',', lineRefNo)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above xsl is used to group lineRefNo and sequence numer to elements of each group

**Java Code:**

```
String xsltPath ="XslFilePath.xsl";     
Source source = new StreamSource("XMLFilePath.xml");

javax.xml.transform.Source xsl = new StreamSource(xsltPath);
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
javax.xml.transform.Result result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(buffer);

javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.transform(xsl, result);
System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Here after transformation i am not getting any result.

**Expected result**

```
Header
LineNo: 1,001,1
LineNo: 2,001,4
Header
LineNo: 1,002,3
LineNo: 2,002,2
LineNo: 3,002,5
Header
LineNo: 1,003,6
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to establish if the problem lies with your XSL or Java code. Try applying the XSL to the XML using a tool or command line processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not an XSLT problem**.

When I apply the provided transformation to the provided XML document, I get what seems to be the wanted result:

```
Header
LineNo: 1,001
LineNo: 2,001
Header
LineNo: 1,002
LineNo: 2,002
LineNo: 3,002
Header
LineNo: 1,003
```

Therefore, you need to find the problem in your Java code that invokes the transformation and then outputs the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your java is actually passing your xsl as the source XML document.

I believe the second last line of your java code should read:

```
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

As it is at the moment, the `source` variable is never actually used.